# How can I deploy ruby-on-rails application in nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, web-deployment

I am deploy a `ruby on rails` application in a `nginx`, my application is as follow:

```
app/
    ...(omit other files)
    views/
        ...(omit other files)
        static_pages/
            ....(omit other files)
            home.html.erb
public/
    404.html
    422.html
    500.html
config/
    routes.rb
....(omit other files)
```

Here is the `routes.rb`:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
     root 'static_pages#home'
 end
```

Here is the `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'faker'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'fog'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.6'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'mini_backtrace'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'unicorn'
end
```

as you can see, my home page is `app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb` and only some error pages are in `public/`.

So how can I config `nginx` to point to my home page?(my application is in `/home/roger/blog/`)

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name example.com;
    location {
        root ?????????;
        index ?????????;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide details on OS and Gemfile and method (process) you use to access your app?

Comment: @borjagvo, of course, my os is ubuntu, my gem file has a little bit too much code, if you still need, I will add it later

Comment: @borjagvo, ok, the Gemfile is added.

Comment: I refer to this document http://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2013/07/19/centos-6-4-server-setup-with-ruby-on-rails-nginx-and-postgresql/. It has a step by step approach.

Answer (score 1):

You don't configure nginx to point to your home page, you configure nginx to proxy traffic to your rails app and the rails app does everything else (with few exceptions).

Here is a simple example that assumes the rails app is listening to socket `/tmp/unicorn.app.sock` and the application root is `/vagrant`.

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  root /vagrant/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
}
```

You can change the root (in your case `/home/roger/blog/public`) and upstream server to whatever is appropriate for your setup (maybe you want to change `unix:/tmp/unicorn.app.sock` to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`).

Here is an example that should work for you with no changes (assuming your app server is listening on port 3000):

```
upstream blog {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  root /home/blog/roger/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @blog;

  location @blog {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://blog;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
}
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit more about why and how to make rails app listening to socket `unix:/tmp/unicorn.app.sock`, what is this?

Comment: In my case I am using unicorn as the app server and I have a file `config/unciorn.rb` that with a line `listen '/tmp/unicorn.app.sock'`.  This tells unicorn to listen to that socket (which is a glorified file in *nix) instead of listening on a port.  It's not necessary but can be nice when you don't want to clutter up ports.  If you don't currently have your rails traffic proxied then I would guess your app server is listening on `localhost:3000` (same as `127.0.0.1:3000`.  I would encourage you to do more research, but this example should get you started with the changes I have described.

Comment: Also, Ryan Bates did a nice railscast on unicorn and nginx [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/293-nginx-unicorn).  In fact my example is pretty much his example verbatim.  It's behind a paywall, but the $9 change is non-recurring since he's not doing them anymore.  Some of the information there is beginning to age, but it's well worth the money and there is a ton of good information there (just be mindful some things may have changed).

Comment: Thank you very much, you have explain very well, I am deploy it with `passenger`

Comment: I am sorry, with your config file, I got 403 error, the error log is`2015/01/21 16:04:48 [error] 12432#0: *1 directory index of "/home/roger/ruby_workspace/hello_app/public/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.44.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.44.131"`. Do you know why is this?(by the way my application is ok in WEBrick)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69278/discussion-between-roger-and-ihaztehcodez).